Npgsql.PostgresException relation "<tablename>" does not exist
I have a Postgres database and tables in the public schema.
I am using Entity Framework to access it.
The table name is question.
This is the Question.cs model class:
[Table("question")]
public class Question
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

This is the code in the OnModelCreating method:
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .ToTable("question")
            .HasMany(q => q.Options)
            .WithOne(o => o.Question)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.QuestionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

When I try a simple query like this one
var qs = await _context.Questions.ToListAsync();

I get this error

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "question" does not exist

What am I doing wrong?
Note: I am using Postgres with EF for the first time, all my previous projects is with SQL Server.
While searching for a solution, I saw many answers which mentions the table name case difference. I don't think that is the case here as I am explicitly using .ToTable() with the correct case.
Edit 1:
including options also
            modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .ToTable("question")
            .HasMany(q => q.Options)
            .WithOne(o => o.Question)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.QuestionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Option>()
            .ToTable("option")
            .HasOne(o => o.NextQuestion)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.NextQuestionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Edit 2:
even without table relationships the problem exists.
ie
            modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .ToTable("question");

same error happens

Looking at your db setup: .HasMany(q => q.Options).WithOne(o => o.Question) begs the question: does this "Options" table exist, and does it in fact have a "Question" navigation property ? Please also show us the Options class, and how it is set up in EF initialization code

After you have configured the relevant class, dbcontext, and relationship, have you run the migration command to generate relevant migrations? You can check whether there are relevant migration files in the Migrations folder of the project.

Please confirm whether your migration has generated the following:
   protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
   {
       migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
           name: "question",
           columns: table => new
           {
               id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                   .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
               text = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false)
           },
           constraints: table =>
           {
               table.PrimaryKey("PK_question", x => x.id);
           });
   }

It was successful for me.

The tables were created manually.

also see edits above, regarding trying without table relationships.

So you only have the 'question' table that cannot be obtained? If so, can the table name be modified? Because I have encountered some table names that are keywords, causing problems

please note that question and option are the only 2 tables in the db currently. And i dont think "question" is a keyword in postgres

Which schema is your table built on?
If you don't set it, the default is public
